# SUBSTITUTE based on a table of replacement strings

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of business names and addresses in A, and shortened versions of just the business names with an added store # shown in B,

[image]

I would like to be able to paste a set of data into column D and have the file automatically find and substitute based on the info in the table, and output to column E.

1. The total number of potential substitutions is >200, so a nested SUBSTITUTE function would very quickly get too messy.
2. The sheet must handle multiples of the same entries in column D. i.e. The same business can appear multiple times in the raw data, and I want each entry to be subbed.
3. A4 and A5 represent the same location for my purposes, so the output needs to be the same between them.
4. A9 include a comma after "Sobeys", so the data formatting is not reliable enough to find the first comma and erase everything after.

This is currently being handled in Google Sheets, but if a more accessible solution exists in Excel I'd be willing to work there just for the substitutions. I've seen similar questions answered using QUERY or ARRAYFORMULA, but I'm out of my depth to try and adjust those answers to suit my needs here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To replace a big amount of data, try this (you have to enable the service `Google Sheets API` )

```
function replacements() {
  const ar = [
    { text: "Example 1", newText: 'text1' },
    { text: "Example 2", newText: 'text2' },
    { text: "Example 3", newText: 'text3' },
  ];
  const requests = ar.map(({ text, newText }) => ({ findReplace: { allSheets: true, find: text, replacement: newText, matchEntireCell: true, matchCase: true } }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
}
```

You can construct the `ar` matrix based on your sheet in a separate spreadsheet (otherwise your table will also update). For instance

```
function replacements() {
  var ar = []
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of the spreadsheet that contains the table').getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues()
  data.forEach(function(r) {
    var prov = {}
    prov['text']=r[0]
    prov['newText']=r[1]
    ar.push(prov)
  })
  const requests = ar.map(({ text, newText }) => ({ findReplace: { allSheets: true, find: text, replacement: newText, matchEntireCell: true, matchCase: true } }));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId());
}
```